# Filling UIImage view with a small image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm working with a UIImage, when the image is larger than the image view, I'd like to aspect fill.

When the image is smaller, I'd like the same for it to stretch it, keeping the aspect ratio but filling it's UIImageView.

Currently, it will just leave the smaller image in it's original size..

Comment: kind of confused...have you tried changing the mode from Scale to Fit to Aspect Fill and thats not working?

Comment: So my situation is I have an image on the left side of a cell, and a view on the right side of the cell. I want the cell's height to depend on the content on the right, and the image on the left to just be aspect fill. If I set a height constraint on the image, to be the same as the right, it's actually growing a large image is in it and causing the right content view to grow (instead of the right side driving the lefts height)... Setting no height gives me the behaviour I want, but smaller images don't fill my image view.